# The .tmux.conf language

Tags: tmux

I'm customizing my `.tmux.conf` and have found lots of other examples on other peoples customization.

Here is one example that apparently makes tmux pane splitting more vim like:

```
set-option -g prefix C-w
unbind-key C-w
bind-key C-w send-prefix
set -g base-index 1

bind-key v split-window -h
bind-key s split-window -v
bind-key h select-pane -L
bind-key j select-pane -D
bind-key k select-pane -U
bind-key l select-pane -R
```

What is the meaning for the syntax for `bind key`, `set` and `set-option`?

Comment: Have you thought to look at the man page?

Comment: @jasonwryan I've updated the question to not ask about the reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tmux configuration file is composed of a sequence of tmux commands that are executed at startup. All commands and options are explained in the [`tmux(1)` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tmux).

Comment: It might be worth mentioning `man tmux` as a command (as well s linking the page online). It's struck me the OP might not even realise documentation comes as standard

Comment: @roaima Started a meta on how to approach this question. https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4734/unixlinux-as-a-platform-of-pragmatic-linux-documentation